# Jackson YAML parsing with parent objects & array of objects

Tags: java, jackson, yaml

I have a yaml file with four parent objects. The fourth object is an array of element of which I will want to create a class for and populate. Is there a way to use the object mapper in jackson to ignore the first three objects and then parse my list of "InspectionModules"?

My yaml file looks like this:

```
# Don't care about these elements
InspectionGroups:
InspecitonModes:
ThresholdTypes:

# This array is of interest
InspectionModules:
 - feature : FC_Trig1
   name: "first inspection"
   Channels:
   - id: ICI_01
     category: Dia_MC_Config
 - feature : FC_Trig2
   name: "Diagonal Missing Cap"
   Channels:
   - id: ICI_02
     category: Dia_MC_Config
```

Basically I want to create a class called InspectionModule and have the mapper map the elements of the InspectionModules array into this class. Is there a simple way to do this in jackson? If not would it be recommended to reorganize our YAML file so we can leverage the object mapper?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you already have some familiarity with Jackson's `ObjectMapper`.

First you will need a Java class representing the entire
contents of your YAML file. Let's call it `Root`:

```
public class Root {

    @JsonProperty("InspectionModules")
    private List<InspectionModule> inspectionModules;

    // getters and setters omitted here for brevity
}
```

Notice that you'll need to use `@JsonProperty` to tell Jackson
that the YAML name `InspectionModules` corresponds to your
Java property `inspectionModules` in spite of their different
spellings.

Next you need a Java class representing one of the
YAML sections below the `InspectionModules:`.

```
public class InspectionModule {

    private String feature;

    private String name;

    @JsonProperty("Channels")
    private List<Channel> channels;

    // getters and setters omitted here for brevity
}
```

And finally you need a `Channel` class representing one of the
YAML sections below `Channels:`
You should be able to write this Java class by yourself already.

Now you are ready to use Jackson's `YAMLMapper` for reading your YAML
file into a `Root` object.

```
File file = new File("example.yaml");
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new YAMLMapper();
objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
Root root = objectMapper.readValue(file, Root.class);
```

Notice that you need to tell Jackson that it is OK to encounter
unknown properties (like `InspectionGroups`) during reading.